# git : switching to different branch without commiting the changes of the branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I have created on branch named as "sub-branch". I am creating on file `test1.txt` after switching to sub-brnach using command `git checkout sub-branch`. Now when i switch to master branch using command `git checkout master` without committing the changes of the sub-branch, the file `test1.txt` is also shown  in master branch.

Why the file `test1.txt` is shown in master branch,since i have created `test1.txt` file in sub-branch so it should be presented in sub-branch only.why git is showing `test1.txt` file in master  branch  also when i do `git checkout master`???.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't commit it in subbranch, it is a private (untracked) file, not attached to any branch.

So when you switch back, that file is ignored and unchanged.

A [`git checkout -f master`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) would remove local changes (but not untracked files).

A `git clean` would, but again, that mean you would loose the file. Start with a `git clean -n` to see a preview.

A `git stash` would save your untracked file (until you apply it again with a `git stash pop`)

Comment: i tried this command but ,the file is still showing in master inspite of not committing.

Comment: @SanjaySalunkhe Ok, I have edited the answer with alternatives

Comment: git stash -u worked for me, since i had some untracked files.Thanks